# Form Request Rule in Laraval 7 Not Working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I'm using laravel 7

I have a Request that I've built but the required rule is not working. Request sends back without any error.

and dd() also not showing request data.

**Function:**

```
public function store(StoreRequest $request)
    {
        dd($request->all());
        if (!auth()->user()->can('add-users')) {
            abort(401);
        }
        try {
            $userStatus = app(CreateUser::class)->execute($request->all());
            if ($userStatus == true) {
                return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'User successfully created.');
            } else {
                return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Oops Something went wrong!');
            }
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            return redirect()->back()->with('error', $ex->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

**Request Code:**

```
class StoreRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => ['required','string','max:255'],
            'email' => ['required','string','max:255'],
            'password' => 'required',
            'organization_id' => 'required'
        ];
    }
}
```

If I use `Illuminate\Http\Request` showing the request data but not validating the data.

Any idea?

Comment: Please show your controller method completely    , I mean with method name and its arguments

Comment: @zohrehda i edit post plz now check

Comment: I see nothing wrong in your code. Check namespaces if you do not have another StoreRequest injected in controller method

Comment: @MahdiRashidi i use 2 requests store and update both at same location but both are not working.

Comment: If the validation fails, you wouldn't enter the controller at all. Are you sure it's getting to the controller, and not just redirecting back with validation errors?

Comment: `Route::resource('user', 'Core\UserController');` this user route.
call it list 127.0.0.1/user

Comment: `The incoming form request is validated before the controller method is called, meaning you do not need to clutter your controller with any validation logic. If validation fails, a redirect response will be generated to send the user back to their previous location. The errors will also be flashed to the session so they are available for display.`

Comment: `{{ \Session::get('error') }}` not showing error

Comment: Try [this section on displaying the validation errors](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors)

Comment: Please don't use `$request->all()` create a record because it's include all $request data and is an insecure way. You should use `$request->validated()` instead.

Comment: Do you use a Resource Controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please can you try this

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'password' => 'required',
        'organization_id' => 'required'
    ];
}
```

Comment: it's also not working

Comment: Can you remove your custom validator, do dd on your request data and  see if you get anything

Comment: it shows the request data. But when validate request same issue there.

Comment: please can you show how do you catch the valodator errors ?